# Arc length of curve stuck with integration

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Data from exercise

$$y=\frac{4}{3}x^2+2\\
x\in[-1,1]$$

Formula for length of curve
$$L=\int_a^{b}\sqrt{1+(f(x)')^2}\ dx$$

So far i have
$$y'=\frac{8}{3}x$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{64}{9}x^2}\ dx$$
Substition
$$t^2=\frac{64}{9}x^2$$
$$t=\frac{8}{3}x$$
$$\frac{3}{8}dt=dx$$
So i have
$$\int_{-\frac{8}{3}}^{\frac{8}{3}}\sqrt{1+t^2}\ dt$$

I this point i dont have a clue how to integrate this

Comment: You could draw the graph of the semicircle and use geometry to find the area or substitute $t=\tan(x)$ and use $\tan^2(x)+1=\sec(x)^2$

Comment: To add to Tyma's comment, you can further use integration by parts to solve the resulting integral. Too tired to type in LaTex today, but hopefully from this point this question is solvable.

Comment: @TymaGaidash ...  think $\sqrt{1+t^2}$ is not a semicircle.

Comment: @GEdgar It was a typo, but the substitution still works

Answer (score 1):

Call the indefinite integral $I$

$$I\equiv\int\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt$$

Through integration by parts with $u=\sqrt{1+t^2}$ and $v=x$, then

$$I=t\sqrt{1+t^2}-\int\frac {t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,\mathrm dt$$

The integrand can also be rewritten as

\begin{align*}
I & =\int\frac {1+t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,\mathrm dt\\ & =\int\frac {\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}+\int\frac {t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,\mathrm dt
\end{align*}

Adding the two expressions for $I$ together and dividing both sides by two eliminates one of the integral terms.

\begin{align*}
I & =\frac 12t\sqrt{1+t^2}+\frac 12\int\frac {\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}
\end{align*}

The last integral is somewhat well-known and can be easily evaluated with an Euler Substitution $x=t+\sqrt{1+t^2}$.

$$\int\frac {\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\log\left(t+\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)$$

Therefore, the indefinite version of the integral becomes

$$\int\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt\color{blue}{=\frac 12t\sqrt{1+t^2}+\frac 12\log\left(t+\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)+C}$$

Now, substitute in the bounds for $t=8/3$ and $t=-8/3$ to arrive at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \sinh \theta \implies$
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int \sqrt{1+x^2}dx \\
&= \int \sqrt{1+\sinh^2 \theta}\cosh \theta d \theta \\
&= \int \cosh^2 \theta d \theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int 1 +  \cosh 2 \theta d \theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sinh 2 \theta + c\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sinh^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1+x^2}+c\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x + \sqrt{1+x^2})+\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{1+x^2}+c
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\sqrt{1+x^2} \:\:dx$$

Let $x=\operatorname{tan}(u)$ $\implies$ $dx=du \operatorname{sec}^2(u)$

therefore our integral becomes $$I=\int\operatorname{sec}^3(u)\:\:du$$ You can easily calculate this using reduction formula or by integration by parts.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#:%7E:text=This%20is%20the%20secant%20reduction%20formula%2C%20which%20follows,%7B%20%28for%20%7D%7Dn%20eq%201%20%7B%20ext%20%7B%29%7D%7D%2C%21%7D)

Don't forget to undo the substitution so that you can apply the limits afterwards.